# PDF Multimedia Component not showing up in the browser

Tags: publishing

In Tridion I uploaded two PDF files as **Multimedia components** into the folder set up as the Images default path of the Publication.

One of such PDF files can be open directly on the browser in a standard way, ex:

> http://domain.com/en/images/file1.pdf

The pdf file opens up and shows its content. However the second PDF file (or multimedia component), which was created in the same way and it's located in the same folder, when being opened in the browser like this

> http://domain.com/en/images/file2.pdf

displays a **404 Error** "*The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable*." I double and triple checked the settings and XMLs for each multimedia component and they look the same to me.

Why is this?

Comment: Where is the Tridion question? When you say that you have the two multimedia pdf uploades intyeo the folder, what do you mean, that the pdf's are published? Are the pdf's physically located in the images path of the web server? Please add more clues.

Comment: It is a Tridion question. The question is why Tridion won't show up a PDF file through the browser while another one can. Sure, the PDFs are physically located in the images path set up in the structure folder as the default images folder. One of the PDFs can be open through the browser and the other one sitting in the same folder can't as it is not found. They're both multimedia components with the exact same settings. Could it be because they need to be called from a published page?

Comment: Are they both published?

Comment: Have you looked on the content delivery server to make sure they are where you think they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a little of misunderstanding in your question.

When you say that the files are in the same folder, I think your are talking about the `Tridion folders` where components of content are located. But what you have to check is if these multimedia files have been published to the "`Delivery side`".

The problem doesn't seem to be a Tridion question, because you are talking that a certain url is not being resolved, and thus, this question is on the web server side, where Tridion publishes their pages and binary files. So the first thing to check is if the binary files (pdf) are located phisically in the path where the server is trying to reach them. If you are publishing to a certain directory in the web server side, check if the two pdf files are there.

By your question it seems that only the "file1.pdf" is going to be there. If it is so, then check that the multimedia component (pdf) in the Tridion side is used in some `Component Presentation` inside a `Page`, and the page is published so the binary is published with the page. Check if the binary component of "file1.pdf" is used the same way as "file2.pdf".

If all is well, then some kind of strange error is happening in the Web Server. Maybe the file names are not as you have put in the question, and some kind of strange character is making the file not accesible. Some kind of server log may be useful to discover the exact problem

Comment: Thanks Raul. This helps enough. So it seems that the PDF besides being created as a multimedia component, has to be used in a component presentation or some other use to be deployed to the delivery side. I'll post any update. Thanks again.